# How can I configure the Google Stack application so that it only backs up when connected to a Wi-Fi network?

Tags: backup, google

I don't see the option in the settings menu of the [Google Stack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.area120.paperwork&hl=en_US&gl=US) Android application:

[image]

[image]

It has uploaded over 10 GB of content today via my 4G network and doesn't seem to stop.

I use Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app isn't available in my country but I checked the reviews. 3 days ago this feature was requested by an user

Developers commented that this would be added in an update due shortly

[image]